# Incrementing values with assignment operators on slice of values in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to apply some basic incremental counting to values held in multi-index dataframe. Can some explain to me why assignment operators on a slice seems to fail with NAN values?

A simple example:

```
df = p.DataFrame({
 'A' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 'B' : ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], 
 'Vals' : 0}).groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()

# These all work as expected:
df.loc['a1', 'b1'] = 3 # Set single value - OK 3
df.loc['a1', 'b1'] += 3 # Increment single value - OK 3 -> 6
df.loc['a1'] = 2 # Set multiple values - OK all 2
```

yet this:

`df.loc['a1'] += 2 # Increment multiple values - fails`

results in

```
       Vals
A  B       
a1 b1   NaN
   b2   NaN
a2 b3   0.0
a3 b4   0.0
```

So it clearly modifies the right selection but somehow doesn't get the correct initial values?

Digging deeper I found:

```
content = df.loc['a1'] # Gives series
content += 500 # Works fine on values of series
df.loc['a1'] = content.values # Need to assign back the values only
```

So it seems the issue is the loc[] is returning a Series, with labels and when this is written back the labels are put into numeric cells - hence the NAN values seen. However I still can't do in one shot as:

```
df.loc['a1'].values += 500
```

throws can't set attribute error.
What is the right way to go about this (applying a fix numeric operation to a slice from dataframe)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc['a1']['Vals']+=500
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: This seems to work, however I'm not clear why this is ok but my initial one isn't. Also this solution is an example of chained indexing, which can result in copy warnings / failures in some cases - see end of here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: The main reason is: while df.loc['a1'] is a dataframe type object, df.loc['a1','Vals'] is a Series type object. You can't perform those kind of operations with dataframe objects. Thanks for your warning, I usually not use chained indexing. I wrote the answer late at night, I missed it.